# What is the purpose of 'set -- $args' after getopt?

Tags: bash, getopt

The usual example for using getopt in bash is as follow

```
args=`getopt abo: $*`
errcode=$?
set -- $args
```

What does that last line achieve?

Comment: It's a very, very bad idea -- anyone who does that is changing `$ ./yourprog "some file.txt"` into `"$ ./yourprog "some" "file.txt"`. See instead http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](http://aplawrence.com/Unix/getopts.html) explains it very well. Essentially, it is to break a single argument with multiple flags into multiple arguments each with single flag:

Whether you call your script as

```
script -ab
```

or as

```
script -a -b
```

after the `set -- $args`, `$1` will be `-a` and `$2` will be `-b`. It makes processing easier.

BTW, `getopts` is much better

Answer (score 4):

`set` updates the positional parameters of the script.

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "$*"
set -- $1 baz
echo "$*"
```

If this script is invoked with `/path/to/script foo bar`, the output is:

```
foo bar
foo baz
```

Comment: One of the things that confused me is that the `--` is used to make that all the parameters after it are used to update the positional parameters, and not interpreted as parameters for the set command itself.